# Why is my Post Processing not working?

Tags: unity, unity-urp

I'm trying to get Post Processing working in my Unity Project, with URP enabled, but I'm not seeing it work. I've looked at a few tutorials and I've followed them exactly, but I never see any post processing happen.

Here's the inspector window for my Camera:

[image]

And here's the inspector window for my Post Processing GameObject:

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure your post processing layer isn't behind the camera, causing it to be invisible?

Comment: @OKprogrammer Camera is on the Default layer, which is 0, and PostProcessing layer is 10

Comment: Its a bug in unity, still unfixed. You need to run your game AT LEAST ONCE to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

[URP comes with its own implementation of post processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html). You cannot use the regular "Post-process Volume" or the "Post-process Layer" with the Universal Render Pipeline. You need to add a different Volume (like the one added in the image below) to add post-processing. Click "Add Component", and search for Volume to add it.

[image: Post-process volume from URP]
[image: Volume]

You also need to make sure the Camera has enabled Post Processing (Which you already have enabled)

[image: Enable Post Processing on camera]

I also use URP in my game, and here is a short gif with and without certain post-processing effects:

[image: Live demo post processing]

Answer (score 0):

Additional info to [John's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194517/54452). Make sure you check following before proceed with John's answer.

### Make sure to remove Post Proprocessing Stack V2 (PPv2)

Go into Window -> Package Manager, Select "In Project" and search for "post processing" package like this one in the screenshot. **The PPv2 package is for built-in renderer not for URP**. You must delete it to prevent confusion.

This is common pitfall if you created your project as built-in renderer then decided to switch to specialized renderer later (URP, etc) your project might be having this package installed.

[image]

Notice that component icon from 2 packages are different:

[image]

And lastly remove your post processing profile asset if it was created with PPv2. The URP one has its own different asset and cannot be interchanged.

[image]